# How to change the array object property values javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have one array object and one array. what are the values in that array that value matched in the array object need to change the status like true.

`arrObj` output should be like below:

```
[
    { name: "Test1", status: true }, 
    { name: "Test2", status: false }, 
    { name: "Test3", status: true }
]
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-7plax5-mu3l6a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```js
let arrObj = [{
    name: "Test1",
    status: true
  },
  {
    name: "Test2",
    status: true
  },
  {
    name: "Test3",
    status: true
  }
]

let arr = ["Test1", "Test3"];

for (k of arr) {
  if (arrObj.name == k) {
    arrObj.status = true;
  }
}

console.log(arrObj);
```

Comment: You are using `arrObj.name`, but `arrObj` is an array: you should access indices on it, and operate on those values.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest method to modify the original array

```js
arrObj.forEach(item => item.status = arr.includes(item.name))

console.log(arrObj);
```

```html
<script>
let arrObj = [{
    name: "Test1",
    status: false
  },
  {
    name: "Test2",
    status: false
  },
  {
    name: "Test3",
    status: false
  }
]

let arr = ["Test1", "Test3"];
</script>
```

[Typescript version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwQeQEYCsYF4YG0BQMMA3oUTGHALYCmAXDAEQAqN0AjIwDRlHRxQArhAYAzOABsINMgF8eRUuQrV6TVtABM3XjH5CRMcVJlF5ZJeUq0GLNlADMO5fuFjJ0ufgC6Abnz4oJCwiAjYeHYc3Or2Tn4BoWjoAHSiIAgAonDAABYAFACWUDRU2AB8MEUlya4Q4aHJBWDAEoIAJmyFxVTJ1jQAlP3+geAQIBI0yRIgAOZ5iRhDQA) runs the same script as I already posted with inferred types

Comment: Any other method?

Comment: @EMahanK You now have 3 methods

Comment: 3 methods Not working in the typescript

Comment: Yes it does. See update with link to TS playground

Comment: Getting error: includes(item.name)  -> Argument of type 'string is not assignable to parameter of type '{name: string; status: boolean '}

Comment: Not working in this case: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-7plax5-exxbth?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Did you mean to post that on [@ScriptHost's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76875254/15261914)? The code the SB is using is as given there.

Comment: @scripthost answer also not working

Comment: What are the values in array that object only status should be true, others it should be false

Comment: Which is what this code does.

Comment: @mplungjan You don't need the type annotation on `arrObj`; it's inferred fine.

Comment: You have any solution for this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-7plax5-exxbth?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @EMahanK Yes, use the code in this answer: it always updates the values, unlike the code you are using, which only ever sets them to `true`.

Comment: mplugjan: Can you update your answer?

Comment: @EMahanK Why? The code given here works. See the SB with it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-7plax5-h8updj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts Unless you mean regards the unneeded type annotation.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes If I do not need it, then the original code worked already, right? (I do not use typescript)

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, the original code works as fine as TS. The type of `arrObj` is inferred, so you do not need to explicitly specify a type (at least for this specific case). Removing the annotation in the linked TS playground produces no error.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the wrong array.
Iterate over `arrObj` and then check if array contains that value using the `indexOf()` method.

```js
let arrObj = [{
    name: "Test1",
    status: false
  },
  {
    name: "Test2",
    status: false
  },
  {
    name: "Test3",
    status: false
  }
]

let arr = ["Test1", "Test3"];

arrObj.forEach(function(k) {
  if (arr.indexOf(k.name) != -1) {
    k.status = true;
  }
});

console.log(arrObj)
```

Comment: function(k)  k is undefined. This is not working function(k:[])